# SQL query to return a report of two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I have two tables, `Answers` and `Users`, which look like this:

```
Answers (AnswerID, QuestionNumber, Answer, UserID)
Users (UserID, FirstName, LastName)
```

What SQL query could I run to return a report like this:

[image]

Comment: Also, if you can provide some sample data it would be helpfull to give a correct answer. Have you tried something, if yes, post your query.

Comment: Do you really want the username as the column header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `PIVOT` function to transform this data. It seems rather unusual that you have the `Name` (Firstname/Lastname) as the headers but if that is what you want, then you can use the following:

```
select *
from
(
  select a.questionnumber,
    u.firstname +' '+ u.lastname as Name,
    a.answer
  from answers a
  left join users u
    on a.userid = u.userid
) src
pivot
(
  max(answer)
  for name in ([John Smith], [Bob Jones])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/666f1/1)

Result:

```
| QUESTIONNUMBER | JOHN SMITH | BOB JONES |
-------------------------------------------
|              1 |       blah |      test |
|              2 |      hsdfk |    (null) |
```

I would think you would want the `Question Numbers` as the headers with the answers below them like this:

```
select *
from
(
  select 'QuestionNumber'+cast(a.questionnumber as varchar(10)) questionnumber,
    u.firstname +' '+ u.lastname as Name,
    a.answer
  from answers a
  left join users u
    on a.userid = u.userid
) src
pivot
(
  max(answer)
  for questionnumber in ([QuestionNumber1], [QuestionNumber2])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17f8e/10)

Result:

```
|       NAME | QUESTIONNUMBER1 | QUESTIONNUMBER2 |
--------------------------------------------------
|  Bob Jones |            test |          (null) |
| John Smith |            blah |           hsdfk |
```

The above answers will work great if you have a known number of items to transform.  But if you have an unknown number, then you can use dynamic SQL to `PIVOT` the data:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME('QuestionNumber'+cast(questionnumber as varchar(10))) 
                    from answers
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Name, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
              select ''QuestionNumber''+cast(a.questionnumber as varchar(10)) questionnumber,
                u.firstname +'' ''+ u.lastname as Name,
                a.answer
              from answers a
              left join users u
                on a.userid = u.userid
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(answer)
                for questionnumber in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/666f1/7)

Result:

```
|       NAME | QUESTIONNUMBER1 | QUESTIONNUMBER2 |
--------------------------------------------------
|  Bob Jones |            test |          (null) |
| John Smith |            blah |           hsdfk |
```

Comment: How would I change "[John Smith], [Bob Jones]" in the first query to return all the users? I tried "(SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Users)"

Comment: @user982119 you would have to hard-code all of the values or you can alter the dynamic version to user the `Users` instead of question numbers.

Comment: @user982119 the query would be similar to this -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/666f1/9

Comment: Absolutely the last additional question: (the latest sqlfiddle you just pasted is working for me) how do I add another column separated by ", ". Ie. a.answer +'', ''+ a.answercomment

Comment: @user982119 I am not sure I understand your last comment/question.  If you want to comma separate the answer and then the comment you can use the following fiddle or something similar -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/69972/1

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. That works on fiddle but when I run it locally I get the error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ', ' to data type int.". It's failing on max(AnswerComment).

Comment: The datatypes must be the same, you might have to perform a conversion of the data.  Can you edit the sql fiddle with you data and then post the link here?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc65d/1 - just changed the 'answer' field to be int instead of varchar

Comment: @user982119 see this fiddle, I converted the `answer` to a `varchar` so it can be concatenated with the `comments` -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a02cb/2

Answer (score 0):

This is called a cross-tab query - there are tons of examples of how to generate them; eg:

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/creating-cross-tab-queries-and-pivot-tables-in-sql/

**EDIT**

@Bluefleet using pivot is probably the best answer; using a simple cross tab may require you to know some aspects of the shape of the data in advance, so the columns are in essence hard coded - if the columns are a stable set then the following should work:

```
declare @Answers table (AnswerID int, QuestionNumber int , Answer int , UserID int)
declare @Users table (UserID int , FirstName varchar(10), LastName varchar(10))
declare @Questions table (QuestionNumber int, QuestionName varchar(10))

insert into @Answers (AnswerID, QuestionNumber, Answer, UserID) values (1, 1, 10, 1)
insert into @Answers (AnswerID, QuestionNumber, Answer, UserID) values (2, 2, 20, 1)
insert into @Answers (AnswerID, QuestionNumber, Answer, UserID) values (3, 3, 30, 2)
insert into @Answers (AnswerID, QuestionNumber, Answer, UserID) values (1, 1, 40, 2)
insert into @Answers (AnswerID, QuestionNumber, Answer, UserID) values (2, 2, 50, 2)
insert into @Answers (AnswerID, QuestionNumber, Answer, UserID) values (3, 3, 60, 3)
insert into @Answers (AnswerID, QuestionNumber, Answer, UserID) values (1, 1, 70, 3)
insert into @Answers (AnswerID, QuestionNumber, Answer, UserID) values (2, 2, 80, 3)

insert into @Users (UserID, FirstName, LastName) values (1, 'Tom', 'Smith')
insert into @Users (UserID, FirstName, LastName) values (2, 'Dick', 'Brown')
insert into @Users (UserID, FirstName, LastName) values (3, 'Harry', 'Robinson')

insert into @Questions (QuestionNumber, QuestionName) values (1, 'Question 1')
insert into @Questions (QuestionNumber, QuestionName) values (2, 'Question 2')
insert into @Questions (QuestionNumber, QuestionName) values (3, 'Question 3')

select 
    QuestionName, MAX(User1) as 'Tom Smith', MAX(User2) as 'Dick Brown', MAX(User3) as 'Harry Robinson'
from 
(
select 
    q.QuestionName,
    (case when a.UserID=1 then Answer else null end) as 'User1',
    (case when a.UserID=2 then Answer else null end) as 'User2',
    (case when a.UserID=3 then Answer else null end) as 'User3'
from @Answers a
join @Users u on u.UserID = a.UserID
join @Questions q on q.QuestionNumber = a.QuestionNumber
) as combined
group by QuestionName



QuestionName Tom Smith   Dick Brown  Harry Robinson
------------ ----------- ----------- --------------
Question 1   10          40          70
Question 2   20          50          80
Question 3   NULL        30          60
```

Comment: I don't think this will work on all databases. We'll first have to know what database is targeted.

Comment: Cross tab queries are a well established pattern on all relational databases - it can be done in all sql variants written since the 1990s that follow the ISO standard.  There is a good cross rdbms example in Joe Celko's mid 1990s book - "Sql For Smarties"

Comment: For dynamic cross-tab columns you need db specific elements (like the stored procedure in your linked article) or Oracle 11g PIVOT function.